# iReport Run On debian with java1.8

Tags: java, linux, ireport

I installed iReport 5.6.0 in my Debian machine but when I lunch it, a first graphical interface  appears for just  few seconds  And this Error appears to me :

"Cannot find java Please use the --jdkhome switch"

solutions that i tried :
- ireport.conf : deleting the "#" before jdkhome= ...
- ireport.conf  : deleting -J-Xmx512m

please any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to removing the `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` from the file `ireport.conf`

I run the command using a JDK 1.7

```
./ireport --jdkhome ~/programas/jdk1.7.0_80/
```

doing this i can run IReport